# Tomcat 7 is not started

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to start Tomcat by running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
```

The output is this:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_92
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

However, Tomcat is not actually started.

When I see logs folder, I see catalina.out file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr  2 13:25 catalina.out
```

That file was created but as you see, with 0 bytes length.

What may be happening here?

By googling, no solution was found.

O.S. is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Can you verify if the java process is running in the background by running this command ps -ef | grep java

Comment: Thanks @AzfarUllahKhan... I have rebooted the server and I could finally start Tomcat. I don't really know what happened.